# SSL/TLS connection to Mosquitto broker from Android app

Tags: mqtt, raspberry-pi, android

I have configured the mosquitto mqtt broker on a raspberry pi via this link

- [SSL/TLS Client Certs to Secure MQTT](http://rockingdlabs.dunmire.org/exercises-experiments/ssl-client-certs-to-secure-mqtt)

I have the ca.crt,client.crt and client.key. How do I use them in android?
It would be really nice if someone could help me out here

Comment: This is really a specific programming question more than a generic IoT question. I would suggest you ask this sort of thing on Stack Overflow (and please do not cross post questions between the 2)

Comment: There are manyMQTT clients for Android out on the Google Play Store....you just need to find one that will let you install the certs and use them :)

Comment: Rather than using self-signed certificates for which you need to tell your client to trust them: use something that your Android client might trust out of the box. Using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) gives you free certificates that are trusted by modern software. (But note that if a browser on your Android device trusts this, it might still not be trusted by Android itself, or some MQTT client running on that device.)

See, for example, https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-ssl-lets-encrypt/

Comment: It'll depend on the app, but with Owntracks you set the certificates in the security section of the connection preferences

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer to this and it can be achieved by creating a .pem file which includes the client.crt and client.key.

Then we can create a .bks using portecle which should contain client.pem, ca.crt and server.crt and then we create a socketfactory with the bks and add that socketfactory to client.